# How to set Selected Item From ListView of MVVM Ligth ViewModelView to another MVVM Ligth ViewModel.?

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I have a `ListView` that is a `View` and this all the properties will assign to the separate `ViewModel` and I want to assign particular property which is selected from the `ListView`.

So the `ListView` bound with `ObservableCollection` object and `SelectedItem` also bound with same object so once I select the item and press <kbd>enter</kbd> that time I want `Selected Item` from the `ObservableCollection` object?

How I can set this value.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but that should probably be handled in the ViewModels.

I would use a messaging system such as MVVM Light's [Messenger](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/) or Microsoft Prism's [EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) to broadcast an event which contains the `SelectedItem` when the Enter key is pressed, and the 2nd ViewModel would subscribe to receive that type of event and could use it's data to do whatever processing you need

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX11/OPN03 where Laurent demo's a master\detail application using MVVM. One aspect is exactly what you are trying to do I think, a selection on the master view gets across to the details view via their associated viewmodels and a bit of messenger magic.